# Pass Multiple Process Creation flags to CreateProcess

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using CreateProcess and I would like to pass `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` as the [Process Creation Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is my pinvoke signature:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Boolean CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            Boolean bInheritHandles, UInt32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, Byte[] lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo);
```

The question is: How to pass multiple flags?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is how to pass multiple flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the flags have a single `1` in a single binary position, you can combine them together by OR-ing or by adding them together:

```
CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

Here is how it works:

```
CREATE_NO_WINDOW  is 0x08000000
CREATE_SUSPENDED  is 0x00000004
```

The result of OR-ing them together is `0x08000004`.