# Show Console Window using CreateProcess?

Tags: c#

My question is how can I show the console instead of hiding it. I do the follow:

```
CreateProcess(path
      ,QuotedPath
      ,IntPtr.Zero
      ,IntPtr.Zero
      ,false
      ,4
      ,IntPtr.Zero
      ,null
      ,ref SI
      ,ref PI);
```

To show my console in the process must I use this value in the six parameter?

```
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes worked but one small question if i want to flag the console because sometimes i want to show it but other times i delete it because it's very annoying. I mean there's some flag to create_new_console and dont show it. like you said: `CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | parameter to make it not visible?`  and make it not visible you understand what i mean? about the question yes it's resolved but it's just this dude.

Comment: Take a look at the process creation flags link in my answer. My guess is you want `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` but it doesn't work with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE `. If it ends up working for you, be sure to mark the answer as accepted, so that you being to earn rep on the site, and gain more privileges.

Comment: Tidy a little, expand code so counting parameters is easier

Answer (score 0):

From the [process creation flags documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx), I grab the values for each flag I'm trying to pass. Then, I [pass the flags using like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438528/4875631):

```
const uint CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004;
const uint CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Boolean CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        Boolean bInheritHandles, UInt32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, Byte[] lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo);

public static MyCreateProcess(path, QuotedPath) {
    CreateProcess(path, QuotedPath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE , IntPtr.Zero, null, ref SI, ref PI);
}
```